# Redirect Loop with Requestmap with grails spring security core 2.0RC4

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have been facing `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` with grails 2.4.4. I have `User`, `Role` and `Requestmap` in `com.usermanagement.auth` package(those were generated with `s2-quickstart`). Requestmaps, users and roles seem to be stored in the database(I am using mysql).

**BuildConfig.groovy**

compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"

**Bootstrap.groovy**
on init method

```
        User admin = new User(username:'admin', password:'secret', enabled:true).save()
        User john = new User(username:'john', password:'secret', enabled:true).save()
        User jane = new User(username:'jane', password:'secret', enabled:true).save()
        Role royalty = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ROYALTY').save()
        Role common = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_COMMON').save()
        UserRole.create(admin, royalty)
        UserRole.create(admin, common)
        UserRole.create(john, common)

        for (String url in [
                '/', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico',
                '/assets/**', '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
                '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
                '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
            new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
        }

        new Requestmap(url: '/*', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/dbconsole/**', configAttribute: 'permitAll').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/index/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/', configAttribute: 'permitAll').save();
```

**Config.groovy**

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.usermanagement.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.usermanagement.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.usermanagement.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.usermanagement.auth.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
```

Whenever I try to access localhost:8080/appname/, this results in too many redirects error after being redirected to `http://localhost:8080/appname/login/auth`. What may be causing this issue? I am even unable to access dbconsole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, this had been a bug as mentioned in https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-312. Spring Security Core is unable to load RequestMaps stored in the database in Grails 2.4.4. I followed a work around mentioned in the link; I basically downgraded the hibernate plugin from 4.3.6.1  to 4.3.5.5. There are other workaround mentioned. But this worked for me.

```
// runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
```

Comment: Tried to use that version of hibernate, didn't worked. I'm not seeing any errors on the console or stacktrace, just receiving the too many redirects in chrome. I'm using grails 2.4.4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with Grails 3.2.3 and spring-security-core:3.1.1. The hibernate5 plugin was causing the problem.  After changing to the hibernate4 plugin, it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Can you please provide you build.gradle file? I'm facing the same issue and have already tried to use hibernate4 instead of hibernate5, but having sill the same problem. I would like to see you working configuration.

Comment: @Tat please provide build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me....

```
    if (!Requestmap.count()) {

        for (String url in [
                '/' , '/error', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico', '/shutdown',
                '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
                '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
                '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*', '/assets/**','/home/repopulate']) {
            new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save(flush:true)
        }

        new Requestmap(url: "/**", configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush:true)

        //TODO: eliminar para cerrar por roles el request
        //new Requestmap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save(flush:true)

    }
    springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()
```