# Grails with with spring_security_core ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.3.3 and have configured spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 with it. Where I am employing the RequestMap the dB table to store the web page access control details for the application.

Starting up the application the login/auth page fails to display due to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have searched earlier stackoverflow posts for ideas and found this one which was useful: [Redirect Loop with Requestmap with grails spring security core 2.0RC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628398/redirect-loop-with-requestmap-with-grails-spring-security-core-2-0rc4)

This refers to another link to a known bug in spring-security-core:
[enter link description here](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-312)

However, this link no longer exists. I searched further and found a useful site the has information on spring_security_core issues: [enter link description here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues). However, this particular issue is not discussed.

Can someone suggest where this old jira web link may have been moved to?

Alternatively, can someone suggest a workaround? The post states that there were a number of suggestions in the original jira post.

I have tried adjusting the Hibernate version which is mentioned in the Stackoverflow post but that didn't work for me. I would welcome some suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security redirects too many times when the User, UserRole and Role table exists but if there is no data.

I would suggest populating these tables with seed data. You can write the seeder code in the Bootstrap.groovy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this isn't the case here as there are two entries for User and Role and UserRole table . But, I think it could be to do with the fact that the original user class domain, which has been linked to SecUser via the 'extends' feature, has some legacy entries in there that were originally used to login into the application prior to incorporating spring_security.

Comment: as I mentioned previously, spring security creates too many redirects, if it can't get an user instance and it roles. Perhaps the way your user domains are setup is causing the issue.

Comment: I believe it could be to do with existing User, which is now being superceded by SecUser via an 'extends', which has other domains that make reference to specific users as foreign keys. I have tried to clean up these references by changing the user id foreign keys to secUser ids via a dbConsole edit. These all fails and produce referential integrity errors. I presume that SecUser can handle foreign key references? And Is this likely to be causing the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS? Is there a way I can resolve this without resorting to deleting all the data in these referenced tables.